# How can I add an event listener to a form when it's loaded as part of a partial page?

Tags: javascript

I have the following page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="darkBlue">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderSection("Content")
    <div class="loading-mask" id="loading-mask" style="display: none;">
        <span>Authenticating ...</span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('form')
                .addEventListener("submit", function () {
                    alert("hi");
                    document.getElementById("loading-mask").style.display = "block";
                }, false);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this partial page:

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Account/Layout.cshtml"; }  
@section content {
   <form action="/Account/Login" class="form" method="post">
      <button type="submit" class="glossy">Login</button>
   </form>
}
```

I want the loading-mask div to become visible when the submit is pressed. However this does not seem to happen. Could this be because my partial is not yet loaded? Can anyone give me some advice how I could make this work?

Comment: Try changing the `button` to `input` `<input type="submit" value='submit'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0]
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('form')
```

That's because [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object instead of an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) one, like [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) does.